# How to choose appropriate token for URL path alias pattern display in URL?

Tags: path-aliases, tokens

Using Drupal 7 + PathAuto + Token + Entity API

Having a really hard time setting url aliases...for nice URLs.
I have it set up like this:

```
[node:field-root:parents]/[node:field-root:name]/[node:title]
```

But it's not what I want, I want every term displayed separately in the URL, now it's like this:

```
 ab/c/d/item
```

but I want:

```
 a/b/c/d/item
```

What token should I use to get this done, tried tons of combinations and can't get it working...

I see the explanations besides the token, but still, it's too complex and I can't wrap my head around this to get it working.

I saw a page that asks users to share their pattern recipes (https://www.drupal.org/node/124462), but there is nothing in there...if I could see a list of patterns and then resulting ULR it would be great.

Otherwise, how do I know what token to choose?

Picture below is hierarchy, the URL I want is:

```
 mysite . com /destinations/northern-laos/outodmxay/history
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
 [node:field-category:parents:join-path]/[node:field-category]/[node:title]
```